# How to open and save ports for Bitnami's MEAN Stack

Tags: port, iptables, bitnami

I'm trying to open and save ports on Bitnami's MEAN Stack.

Steps I've followed so far:

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
sudo su
iptables-save > /opt/bitnami/iptables-rules
iptables-restore < /opt/bitnami/iptables-rules
sudo reboot`

When I reboot, port 3000 is closed. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use 'ufw' from Ubuntu. It is very simple to open a port and it preserves the configuration if you reboot the server.

```
$ sudo ufw allow 3000
```

Comment: had high hopes for this. Having trouble getting ec2 to listen in on 6443. Any ideas? This one didn't work. I did something like this and got nothing: bitnami@ip-172-31-4-196:~$ sudo ufw allow 6443
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure `iptables` to restore the specified rules from the saved file on start-up. On its [troubleshooting page](https://wiki.bitnami.com/BitNami_Cloud_Hosting/Servers/Troubleshooting#How_to_block_a_suspicious_IP), `BitNami` recommends using [`crontab`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) to do so:

> If you want to have your iptables rules active when you reboot your
>   machine you have to do the following:
>
> ```
> sudo su
> iptables-save > /opt/bitnami/iptables-rules
> crontab -e
> ```
>
> Now edit the file with your favourite editor and include this line at the end of the file:
>
> ```
> @reboot /sbin/iptables-restore < /opt/bitnami/iptables-rules
> ```
>
> Save the file and exit. This way, in every boot, the system will load the iptables rules and apply them.